# Wpf retrieving data from database freeze UI

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a problem with async retrieving data from database, everytime i get UI lock.

```
private async void RetrieveHotlist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //button click
    {
        var hotItems = new ObservableCollection<HotItem>();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                try
                {
                    var serv = "xxx";
                    string connStr = Common.GetConStrEF(serv + "\\" + Common.DBLOGIN_INSTANCE,
                                                        Common.DBLOGIN_DBNAME, Common.DBLOGIN_USER, Common.DBLOGIN_PASSWORD);
                    var dataModel = new xxxxDataModel(connStr);

                    foreach (var category in dataModel.SpecialNumberCategory)  //retrieving database CreateObjectSet<SpecialNumberCategory>("SpecialNumberCategory"); //ObjectContext
                    {
                        var item = new HotItem() {  Name = category.Name };
                        hotItems.Add(item);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    var baseException = exception.GetBaseException();
                    MessageBox.Show("Error\n\n" + exception.Message + "\n\n" + baseException.Message);
                }

            });
        if (Settings != null)
        {
            Settings.Hotlist.Clear();
            foreach (var hotItem in hotItems)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => Settings.Hotlist.Add(hotItem)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Why the RetrieveHotlist method locks my UI? And why await Task.Factory.StartNew() it's not enough?

Thanks for help :)

**EDIT:**

I deleted some code to be more clear.

```
private void RetrieveHotlist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //button click
    {
        var b = new BackgroundWorker();
        b.DoWork += (o, args) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); //**UI IS FULL RESPONSIVE FOR 2 sec.**
                var hotItems = new ObservableCollection<HotItem>();
                try
                {

                    var serv = "xxxx";
                    var dataModel = new xxxxDataModel(connStr);
                    var c = dataModel.SpecialNumberCategory; //**UI FREEZE / ENTITY FRAMEWORK**


        b.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
            {

            };
        b.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

**EDIT2:**
Thanks all for help, Entity Framework caused the issue ( i don't know why for now).

I replaced all model lines with SqlConnection and SqlCommand.Now it works great.

Comment: You should retrieve data on a separate thread and display message dialogs, UI changes on a different one. We have what we called UI thread where all UI-related actions should be called.

Comment: are you sure above is your code? await can only be used with async methods, above code can't even be compiled...

Comment: are you sure that the following row `hotItems.Add(item);` does not throw any exception?

Comment: @Ephraim I've tried with background worker, it was the same. I'll try with new Thread.

Comment: @Kylo Ren & StepUp - Code is correct, no errors and exceptions :) StartNew is awaitable.

Comment: @PawełCharzewski ok get it. it is awaitable when current methos is async... I think Settings.Hotlist is you are displaying on UI or somehow it is connected to any UI component. Am I right?

Comment: @Kylo Ren Yes, you're right. Settings.Hotlist is binded to ItemSource of ListBox.

Comment: @Kylo Ren even without touching Settings.Hotlist the UI is freezed :(

Comment: @PawełCharzewski what do you mean without touching the Settings.Hotlist ? have you run your code after commenting the last if block ? Also you are displaying the messagebox in catch block, this is not allowed to use UI components for other threads other than UI thread

Answer (score 0):

UI-related codes should be invoked on the UI-thread. Don't mix this with the same thread where you manipulate data (send, retrieve, update, etc.) to avoid deadlocks. On your case it was caused by the interaction with the database.

Here is an example:

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { 
    /* Your code here */ 
    MessageBox.Show("Error\n\n" + exception.Message + "\n\n" + baseException.Message);
}));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.
Sadly it's still the same..
All things related to UI I surrounded by Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>

Comment: Also make sure you are not calling the RetrieveHotlist method inside Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: I think it's automatically... 
because it's button click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `RetrieveHotlist()` is blocking the `UI` cause below code

```
           foreach (var hotItem in hotItems)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => Settings.Hotlist.Add(hotItem)));
            }
```

is getting executed on main `Thread`. If you see closely the problem must be your are adding item one by one to the `list` and every time a item is added to your `Hotlist` it must be raising the change to `UI`, even if it's not doing it on every item add event happens, it will take some time to iterate a `collection` and add items to another `collection`, which is your freeze time of UI thread.

To avoid this you can directly assign the `hotItems` to `Hotlist`( by using corresponding Ienumerable conversion). If you can give me type of  `Hotlist` I can give you exact syntax. or you can prepare a temporary collection first of compatible type and then assign that collection to `Hotlist`. **The key point is to minimize the work at UI thread.** Replace whole `foreach`  as below:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => Settings.Hotlist.AddRange(hotItems)));
```

and move the work done by `foreach` in your `Thread`. Now in the `Action` , either use `AddRange()`, do an `assignment` or anything to make it work.

Comment: please check the edited post,
Now I know the UI freezeng is caused by :dataModel.SpecialNumberCategory;

Comment: @PawełCharzewski by judging from your comment it doesn't seem possible that in a async operation one part is executing fine and another is blocking the UI. the only problem I can think of is your xxxxDataModel (or any inner component) is somehow related to UI thread. Can you give code of that class too?

Comment: sorry but I can't :(
It's simple class generated by entity framework

Comment: @PawełCharzewski If it's a simple class then i think there is no way it can block the UI. Problem must be where UI thread is working in your method and that only can be RunWorkerCompleted block or Dispatcher actions.

Comment: @PawełCharzewski in your first code block I'm 100% sure it's the iteration and adding items using dispatcher is causing the problem. There may be a contextual possibility that your new task may be blocking the UI which I can't create here. but other than that approach was fine.

Comment: ok..i think that too.But what with second code block? I'll try to make it easier without EF.

Comment: @PawełCharzewski what are you doing in the RunWorkerCompleted in the second code block?

Comment: @PawełCharzewski ok. may be you can try this by creating a dummy collection in try block without using connection of DB to narrow down the problem.